# How to run a imagemagick powershell script in terminal (osx)?

Tags: macos, powershell, terminal, imagemagick, automator

I'm trying to create an automation that converts any image into a "cover photo" for Notion.

There is a PowerShell script called "[Notion Cover Script](https://github.com/tpfrois/notion-cover-script)" that can achieve this in OSX's Terminal, but I'd like to create an Automator action that runs the "Notion Cover Script" whenever an image is added to a folder on my desktop.

Here is the script

```
input=$1
output=$2

color=$(magick convert $input -scale 5x5 -format '%[pixel:u]' info:-)
magick convert $input -resize 1500x300 -gravity center -background $color -extent 1500x300 $output
```

I've installed the relevant dependencies via Terminal (ImageMagick), but as I'm new to terminal *and* Automator, I'm unsure how to set this action up.

The developer simply states that I need to

> 1. Execute the script file with Powershell
> 2. Enter the image name: e.g. `cover.png`
> 3. Enter the name for the converted image: e.g. `cover-converted.png`

But despite researching (and contacting the developer) I can't seem to figure out what the resulting query would look like in terminal.

Would somebody be able to help me figure this out, please?

**SOLUTION:** turns out the solution was to resolve an error in the source code, and I needed to run in bash using the "Magick" instead of "Magick convert"

Comment: That's not a PowerShell script, it's bash or zsh :) Try `/usr/local/bin/bash path/to/script cover.png cover-converted.png`

Comment: The **Run Shell Script** action can run a shell script, but note that the folder action will be triggered again if the workflow adds to or renames files in the watched folder.  Is there a destination folder set up for the converted files?

Comment: If you are using Imagemagick 7, then use magick, not magick convert.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your suggestions - turns out the solution was a combination of all of your replies.

Comment: 1. As I was using Imagemagick 7, I needed to delete the "convert" from the code and only use "magick". (thank you @fmw42)

Comment: 2. @red_menace your feedback helped me see an error in the source code from the repo - which used a "\" instead of "/". I filed an issue on GitHub so the dev knows

Comment: 3. @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks to you, I changed to bash.

Thank you so much everyone - truly grateful for the time you took to patiently explain it to me.

Comment: @CJK, Absolutely - it's in the original post, and sharing [here for ease](https://github.com/tpfrois/notion-cover-script)